# Send to using batch file

Tags: batch-file, contextmenu

Hi i have a main folder that contains two folders "active" and "confirmed".
The subfolders under these two folders are identical. I want to be able to select the files i need to send to the confirmed folder through the windows context menu but i can't get this code to work.

```
for %%i in (%*) do (
    REM Takt the path of each file and save it as source.
    source=%%i
    REM Change the word "active" in the path to "confirmed".
    destnation=%%i:active=confirmed%

    REM Move the file to the confirmed subtree. 
    move /-Y source destination
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `SET` command to assign a string to a variable. You also cannot do string substitution with a `FOR` variable.  You also need to use delayed expansion to reference your variables inside a code block.

Give this a try.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (%*) do (
    REM Take the path of each file and save it as source.
    set "destination=%%~dpI"
    REM Change the word "active" in the path to "confirmed".
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "destination=!destination:active=confirmed!"
    REM Move the file to the confirmed subtree. 
    move /-Y "%%~I" "!destination!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the post unfortunately it did not work and i'm too new at this to understand what it does but I just started an education to learn more :)

Comment: @PatrickBender, it should do what you want it to do based on the description of your question.  You are dragging and dropping files onto a batch file from the active folder.  You said the path structure is the same for the active and confirmed folders, so all we have to do is change the word active to confirmed.  It then moves the files you dropped onto the batch file to the confirmed folder and prompts you to overwrite if there is already an existing file.

Comment: Awesome, i must have missed something beacuse now it works well!

Comment: Well I misspelled echo. But that will not cause any problems with the code.

Comment: Is there a way to also avoid showing the console window?

Comment: @PatrickBender, as I said in my previous comment.  I misspelled echo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155457/discussion-between-patrick-bender-and-squashman).